# How can I build a Model Structure such as Laravel Models?

Tags: php, oop

I try to create a model like "Laravel Model".

I have a mysql table. Its name is "users". There are 3 users in the table.

1- Steve Rogers
2- Obadiah Stane
3- Tony Stark

I made a model but not working. My codes:

```
abstract class Model
{
    protected static $properties = array();

    public static function find($id)
    {
        global $config;

        try {
            $db = new PDO($config['dsn'], $config['user'], $config['password']);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die ('Connect problem: <pre>' . $e->getMessage() . '</pre>');
        }
        $db->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'; SET CHARSET 'utf8'");

        $row = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".static::$table." WHERE id='".$id."' LIMIT 1")->fetch();

        if ($row)
        {
            foreach ($row as $key => $value)
            {
                if (is_numeric($key)) continue;
                static::$properties[$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $row ? new static : false;
    }

    public function __get($property)
    {
        return static::$properties[$property];
    }
}
```

I use the following:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public static $table = 'users';
}

$k1 = User::find(1);
$k2 = User::find(2);
$k3 = User::find(3);

echo $k1->name." ".$k1->lastname."<br>".$k2->name." ".$k2->lastname."<br>".$k3->name." ".$k3->lastname;
```

Result:

> Tony Stark
> Tony Stark
> Tony Stark

I want this result:

> Steve Rogers
> Obadiah Stane
> Tony Stark

Where is my mistake?

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel: http://www.edzynda.com/use-laravels-eloquent-orm-outside-of-laravel/

Comment: Your mistake is `static` for the properties..... Laravel isn't using statics, it's using facades

Comment: And the use of `foreach ($row as $key => $value)` with the assumption that `$key` will be different for every request, and match the primary key of the record that you're retrieving from the database

Comment: Thanks for your answers :)